# I want to implement comments section similar to that of facebook using angularJs and ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Please can you help me what approach should I follow, particularly I have implement a comment section were people can comment on the photo or post. It will just be commenting page and on which person who is commenting his profile photo will appear along with his comment.
I am using ionic and angularJs as front end technologies and parse at the backend to develop this functionality.

Please help me out!!

Comment: Good luck with that! Joke aside, please post more specific questions, this is too broad. Also, let us know a little about your research for this problem and where you got stuck.

Comment: @lulian I searched for it, currently only reactJs is having such tutorial but no tutorial available using ionic+angularJs

Comment: Please specify your problem definition !

Answer (score 0):

Can you look into this once: http://devzone.co.in/angularjs-example-simple-user-comment-box/, It may help you.